# phpactiverecord causing foreacho loop to fail

Tags: php, foreach

I have an update function that I have written inside of one of my php activerecord models.  For some reason it is causing the foreach loop to send back invalid argument supplied for foreach

```
public static function set_price($prices)
{
    foreach ($prices as $key => $value)
    {
        $item = Quote_Item::find($key);
        $stuff = $item->update_attribute('price', $value);
    }
}
```

I have verified that prices is an array and that the item is being found correctly. I have checked enough things to know that this line is causing the problem  $stuff = $item->update_attribute('price', $value); I don't really see how it can affect a foreach loop?

Comment: As an added note I have checked everything in the DB to ensure that I have the right fields

Comment: I couldn't find the method `update_attribute` on PHPActiveRecord documentation, are you sure it exists?

Comment: Yes, have used it several times. I've also tried it this way with the same results $item->price = $value;
       $item->save();

Comment: Since you're getting "invalid argument supplied for foreach" error, it could be your `$prices` that's faulty.

Comment: I've verified the heck out of everything.  If I take out the line that I mentioned it doesn't throw any errors. I've also run is_array() on prices.

Comment: Oddly enough I just tried to run it as a standalone lookup and got invalid argument supplied for foreach from this $item = Quote_Item::find(9);
   $item->update_attributes(array('price' => 100.0));

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't know what's going on. What about the your database? did you have the right datatype and sufficient length for the column price?

Comment: I figured it out .... It was the name of my function.  Active record must generate setters and getters or something like that and they were conflicting somehow.  I changed the name of the function and it fixed it.